# "Unfortunately, has stopped" eclipse android avd

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

In the eclipse/android AVD, I get "Unfortunately, has stopped"

Help please.. here is the code
I just follow the other codes...

I tried everything I can I just don't know 
what to do ...

help help help... not a total programmer ...

```
package com.somedomain.animatedinteractive;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;    
import android.graphics.Color;        
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {    
    WebView mWebView;    
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */    

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation" )
    @Override    
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.action_settings);            
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);           
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);            
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Parable_Book.swf");             
        mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);     
        mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }

}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `main` layout does not have a `WebView` with id `action_settings`. Change

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.action_settings);
```

to

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Also, when getting an "unfortunately app has stopped" message, it's a good idea to have a look at the exception stacktrace in logcat. Include it in your question, too.

Comment: @laalto i tried what you answered but the problem now is it dont show may swf file ..,, it only flash a black screen..

Comment: Is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492261/how-can-i-play-a-swf-file-using-webview-and-accessing-the-file-from-my-assets-di helpful?

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.somedomain.animatedinteractive;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.graphics.Color;


import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView mWebView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation" )
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);



        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Parable_Book.swf"); 

        mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY); 

        mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }

}

main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: It's generally a good idea to explain to OP what you changed and why rather than just post code, otherwise they don't learn anything from it